# How to deal with the deprecated offline_access?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have an application which uses offline_access to get permanent access to different pages.

Users can install this application and add it to pages, where they are admins.
With an external Backend they can administrate their app and let it post different things (Competitions, ...).
So they don't have to stay logged in to Facebook.

Now... there is the problem...

On May 1st the offline_access permission will be removed and the customers have to get a new Token for their Pages every 60 days.

Since now I'm using the offline_access feature for our customers to get non-expiring Page-Tokens.

Is there any workaround for that?
Often it's just a Facebook sub-account of the customers to run the app. So it's possible that they don't login for 60+ days = the access token will expire and the application won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get an page login access_token for a facebook page, that does NOT expire?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9236369/how-do-i-get-an-page-login-access-token-for-a-facebook-page-that-does-not-expir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redirect them to a link of your app in facebook when their access token expired like this 
http://apps.facebook.com/xxx/reaccess.php?ref=REF_URL
Get new access_token & redirect user back to your app's original page  again

i dont think you be needed to ask them again for permissions

Comment: Thanks :) I think we will use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remind the user to re-authorize access before the expiration of the token. Do this by sending them an app-to-user request **and** and an email (because app-to-user requests don't generate a notification). In the email include a link directly to a web page which instantly pops up the authorization dialog (and do something similar with the app-to-user request).